# Xfce4 - Deactive rolling in of window

Tags: xfce, window

How can I stop the behaviour that when I put **my cursor over the title bar** and then **turn my mouse wheel**, **the window gets rolled in**?
It is really annoying and happens accidentally quite often.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally found a solution:

1. Open the xfce4-settings-editor via terminal
2. Click xfwm4 / general / mousewheel_rollup and **uncheck** the enable box

[image]

Thats it :)

Comment: Thank you sir, you saved my day (very annoying behavior indeed).

Answer (score 5):

Rolling seems to be enabled by default still in Xubuntu 18.04. Here's the setting:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The recent xfwm4 4.11.1 development release (hence the upcoming Xfce 4.12) will contain the following:

- Add tweak setting to toggle roll up feature (bug #10563).
- Disable roll up feature by default (bug #10563).